# Non sorted eigenvalues for finding features in Python

Tags: python, pca

I am now trying some stuff with PCA but it's very important for me to know which are the features responsible for each eigenvalue.

`numpy.linalg.eig` gives us the diagonal matrix already sorted but I wanted this matrix with them at the original positions. Does anybody know how I can make it?

Comment: There is no natural order of eigenvalues and no "original position".

Comment: ok, but the eigenvalues calculated for the same matrix in Python and in R, gives me the same values in different order.

Comment: @jozepinta: I told you, there is no natural order.  You have to choose one.  Python and R happen to choose a different one, but both of these orderings are arbitrary choices.

Answer (score 1):

What Sven mentioned in his comments is correct. There is no "default" ordering of the eigenvalues. Each eigenvalue is *associated* with an eigenvector, and *it is important* is that the eigenvalue-eigenvector pair is matched correctly. You'll find that all languages and packages will do so.

So if R gives you eigenvalues `[e1,e2,e3` and eigenvectors `[v1,v2,v3]`, python probably will give you (say) `[e3,e2,e1]` and `[v3,v2,v1]`.

Recall that an eigenvalue tells you how much of the variance in your data is explained by the eigenvector associated with it. So, a natural sorting of the eigenvalues (that is intuitive to us) that is useful in PCA, is by size (either ascending or descending). That way, you can easily look at the eigenvalues and identify which ones to keep (large, as they explain most of the data) and which ones to throw (small, which could be high frequency features or just noise)

Answer (score 0):

(Not an answer, but I need advanced formatting for this comment.)

You have to specify what ordering gyou want.  E.g., the eigenvalues of this matrix

```
    / 0  1 \
A = |      |
    \ 1  0 /
```

are `+1` and `-1`, corresponding to the eigenvectors `(1 1)` and `(1 -1)`.  How would you like these eigenvalues to be ordered, and why?